# Set font does not affect the appearance of cells in output excel file

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I try to give Persian text and numbers in xlsx. I want the numbers to be displayed in Arabic and Persian

[image: pdf report image]

As you can see, Persian font is applied and the numbers are in Persian but not so in xlsx

[image: xlsx report img]

As you see font set but not applied On the other hand, the "B Farnaz" font is installed in the Windows operating system

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<jasperReport
        xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd"
        name="rptReport"
        pageWidth="842"
        pageHeight="595"
        orientation="Landscape"
        columnWidth="802"
        leftMargin="20"
        rightMargin="20"
        topMargin="20"
        bottomMargin="20"
        whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xlsx.exclude.origin.band.1" value="pageHeader"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xlsx.exclude.origin.band.2" value="pageFooter"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xlsx.exclude.origin.band.3" value="title"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.crosstab.ignore.width" value="true"/>
    <style name="textStyle"  hTextAlign="Center" vTextAlign="Middle" fontName="B Farnaz"  fontSize="10" pdfFontName= "C:/fonts/nazanin.ttf" pdfEncoding="Identity-H"/>
    <parameter name="reportName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="currentDate" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="number" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="pageName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="ofName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="logo" class="java.io.InputStream"/>
    <field name="count" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="organizationId" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="orgName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="orgCode" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="orgTypeName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="positionId" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="title" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="orgParentName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <title>
        <band height="61">
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="802" height="60" uuid="e0e43037-9be9-410e-9e49-9f03a811629b"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </rectangle>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="70" y="13" width="40" height="20" uuid="80c01bc2-7498-4a53-9183-9716832fa86e"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font  fontName="B Farnaz"  size="14" pdfFontName= "C:/Users/m.shadkam/Desktop/PORTAL/portal-server/src/main/resources/report/fonts/nazanin.ttf" pdfEncoding="Identity-H"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[تاريخ :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="70" y="35" width="40" height="20" uuid="df222e3e-0a63-4cff-8b4a-7b7d6cdad5b2"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font  fontName="B Farnaz"  size="14" pdfFontName= "C:/Users/m.shadkam/Desktop/PORTAL/portal-server/src/main/resources/report/fonts/nazanin.ttf" pdfEncoding="Identity-H"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[شماره :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <image hAlign="Right">
                <reportElement x="690" y="13" width="110" height="44" uuid="6b166494-6df6-4472-8140-da4f93644616"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{logo}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="3" y="35" width="65" height="20" uuid="52b5428c-f329-4d65-be61-51e529269ca7"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font  fontName="B Farnaz" pdfFontName= "C:/fonts/BNAZANIN.TTF" pdfEncoding="Identity-H"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{number}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="">
                <reportElement x="0" y="1" width="802" height="35" uuid="c9904a66-50ba-4cee-9fa9-b6b29feec8b0"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font  fontName="B Farnaz" size="14" pdfFontName= "C:/fonts/titr.ttf" pdfEncoding="Identity-H"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{reportName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="">
                <reportElement x="3" y="13" width="65" height="20" uuid="fdc85694-ba29-4858-915e-23399415a806"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font  fontName="B Farnaz" pdfFontName= "C:/fonts/BNAZANIN.TTF" pdfEncoding="Identity-H"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{currentDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="20">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="739" y="0" width="63" height="20" />
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font  fontName="B Farnaz" pdfFontName="C:/fonts/BNAZANIN.TTF" pdfEncoding="Identity-H"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{pageName} + " " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER} + " " + $P{ofName} +" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="23" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="2" width="802" height="20" uuid="b8f61bae-86d8-4a73-8c23-3484b431a65e"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font  fontName="B Farnaz" pdfFontName= "C:/fonts/BNAZANIN.TTF" pdfEncoding="Identity-H"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height = "79">
            <crosstab ignoreWidth="true">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" height="79" width="500"/>
                <crosstabHeaderCell>
                    <cellContents backcolor="#F0F8FF" mode="Opaque">
                        <box>
                            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement style="textStyle"  x="100" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
                            <box>
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            </box>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["اداره امور"]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement style="textStyle"  x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
                            <box>
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            </box>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["واحد/کادر"]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabHeaderCell>
                <rowGroup name="orgName" width="100" totalPosition="End">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{orgName}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabRowHeader>
                        <cellContents backcolor="#F0F8FF" mode="Opaque">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement style="textStyle" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="25" uuid="722e2c03-df3c-4012-aecf-91b7a8bad18d"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{orgName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabRowHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                        <cellContents backcolor="#BFE1FF" mode="Opaque">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement  style="textStyle" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="25" uuid="4e9afca3-c0a3-4182-b3ce-9afb39fd3468"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[کل]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                </rowGroup>
                <rowGroup name="orgParentName" width="100" totalPosition="End">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{orgParentName}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabRowHeader>
                        <cellContents backcolor="#F0F8FF" mode="Opaque">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement style="textStyle" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="25" uuid="63804c09-f3f6-401f-8598-fa2e35860a8f"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{orgParentName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabRowHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                        <cellContents backcolor="#BFE1FF" mode="Opaque">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                </rowGroup>
                <columnGroup name="title" height="100"  totalPosition="End">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{title}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents backcolor="#F0F8FF" mode="Opaque">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement style="textStyle" x="0" y="0" width="25" height="100" uuid="7edd05fd-4252-404d-bb82-54a705040663"/>
                                <textElement rotation="Left"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{title}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabColumnHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents backcolor="#BFE1FF" mode="Opaque">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement  style="textStyle" x="0" y="0" width="25" height="100" uuid="de037370-9595-4ab0-8d55-ec94159f9ca0"/>
                                <textElement rotation="Left"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[کل]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                </columnGroup>
                <measure name="countMeasure" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
                    <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{count}]]></measureExpression>
                </measure>
                <crosstabCell width="25" height="25">
                    <cellContents>
                        <box>
                            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement style="textStyle" x="0" y="0" width="25" height="25" uuid="2de587ed-74f0-46c2-8425-5a4e9bd120e6"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{countMeasure}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell height="25" rowTotalGroup="orgName">
                    <cellContents backcolor="#BFE1FF" mode="Opaque">
                        <box>
                            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement style="textStyle"  x="0" y="0" width="25" height="25" uuid="e7dd4c40-847f-4df0-b910-f99566746ecb"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{countMeasure}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="25" columnTotalGroup="title">
                    <cellContents backcolor="#BFE1FF" mode="Opaque">
                        <box>
                            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement style="textStyle" x="0" y="0" width="25" height="25" uuid="2ed6a617-5440-4bee-931e-dc4e16f0539d"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{countMeasure}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell rowTotalGroup="orgName" columnTotalGroup="title">
                    <cellContents backcolor="#BFE1FF" mode="Opaque">
                        <box>
                            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement style="textStyle" x="0" y="0" width="25" height="25"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{countMeasure}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell height="0" rowTotalGroup="orgParentName">
                    <cellContents backcolor="#BFE1FF" mode="Opaque">
                        <box>
                            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell height="0" rowTotalGroup="orgParentName" columnTotalGroup="title">
                    <cellContents backcolor="#BFE1FF" mode="Opaque">
                        <box>
                            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
            </crosstab>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

I used Persian font in the report, but this Persian font is not applied in the xlsx version of the report, but is applied correctly in the pdf version.

I also used the font exception to solve this problem but it did not work for the excel version.

Please help me to display the text and numbers in xlsx like pdf correctly